# Why is my character's backpack pointing in a different direction in Half-Life Model Viewer? (Blender To Source Filmmaker)

Tags: modeling, animation

While my character is connected to the rig, the backpack model in the photo is looking in a different direction. But if I use the Clear Parent option after right-clicking on the model, the backpack is facing the right direction in Half-Life Model Viewer. But this is not the solution. The rig works fine but I think the rotation problem is in the rig. But I don't know what to do.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

Comment: I would check docs on the addon you’re using to export the model.

Comment: This is impossible. I don't have such a problem yesterday and the same plugin was installed. But I still deleted the existing plugin and downloaded the latest version. This action did not solve my problem.

Comment: I said check docs, aka the documentation. Not check the version.

Comment: I can't check the files as I don't understand the Python language at all.

Comment: I mean the documentation on the addon as in the instructions on how to properly use it as provided by the distributer. This appears to be an issue with the addon, not with blender.